# How to make concurrent network requests using OKHTTP?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, okhttp

I'm looking for a best practice for making concurrent network requests using the OKHTTP library.

Basically here's what I want to do:

**I want to write a method that makes N concurrent network requests to different URLs, and return ONLY when ALL N requests have returned.**

I thought about manually writing Threads and Runnables and such to create a group of request pool, but was wondering if there's some sort of easier way to do this. So my question is:

1. Does OKHTTP support concurrent request API natively somehow?
2. If not, what's the best way to implement this?

Comment: RxJava around OkHttp could help you

Comment: you can use `countDownLatch` either, initialize that with N and use `await` in non UI thread because this will be block your thread, then in oSuccess of each request call `countDown`, after `await` do what you want.

Answer (score 17):

OkHttp natively supports asynchronous requests efficiently e.g. sharing the optimum number of connections.

See https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/samples/guide/src/main/java/okhttp3/recipes/AsynchronousGet.java

For the second part of the question, you use a CountdownLatch or you can bridge to java Futures like the [following](https://github.com/yschimke/oksocial/blob/3757196cde420b9d0fe37cf385b66f4cdafb1ae1/src/main/java/com/baulsupp/oksocial/okhttp/OkHttpResponseFuture.java)

```
public class OkHttpResponseFuture implements Callback {
  public final CompletableFuture<Response> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

  public OkHttpResponseFuture() {
  }

  @Override public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
    future.completeExceptionally(e);
  }

  @Override public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
    future.complete(response);
  }
}
```

And call

```
  private Future<Response> makeRequest(OkHttpClient client, Request request) {
    Call call = client.newCall(request);

    OkHttpResponseFuture result = new OkHttpResponseFuture();

    call.enqueue(result);

    return result.future;
  }
```

At that point you can use methods like [CompletableFuture.allOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html)

n.b. if you wrap with Futures, it can be easy to not close the Response objects when one fails.